# Pygame Text Line Break

Tags: python, text, pygame

I am writing codes which search program with pygame, wikipedia

This is part of my codes

```
display = pygame.display.set_mode((420, 990))

sem = pygame.font.Font("fonts.ttf", 30)

def write(msg, color, x, y):
    surface = sem.render(msg, True, color)
    display.blit(surface, (x,y))
```

then, I can render text.
and next, Type words what I want to get information in wikipedia(code skip):
and get information in wikipedia(next line)
result = wikipedia.summary(search, sentences=2)

but if i write long sentence, the result is like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJAqB.png)

The sentence is cutted.
So, I want this result like this:

Previous

Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the fl

Desired result

Stack Overflow is a privately held website, the
flow(sentence continue)

How can I line break in pygame?
(But I don't know sentence length

Answer (score 2):

Here's a running  example (using the `word_wrap` function [from the documentation](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to)):

```
import pygame
import pygame.freetype
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((100, 200))
running = True

def word_wrap(surf, text, font, color=(0, 0, 0)):
    font.origin = True
    words = text.split(' ')
    width, height = surf.get_size()
    line_spacing = font.get_sized_height() + 2
    x, y = 0, line_spacing
    space = font.get_rect(' ')
    for word in words:
        bounds = font.get_rect(word)
        if x + bounds.width + bounds.x >= width:
            x, y = 0, y + line_spacing
        if x + bounds.width + bounds.x >= width:
            raise ValueError("word too wide for the surface")
        if y + bounds.height - bounds.y >= height:
            raise ValueError("text to long for the surface")
        font.render_to(surf, (x, y), None, color)
        x += bounds.width + space.width
    return x, y

font = pygame.freetype.SysFont('Arial', 20)

while running:
    for e in pygame.event.get():
        if e.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    word_wrap(screen, 'Hey, this is a very long text! Maybe it is too long... We need more than one line!', font)
    pygame.display.update()
```

Result:

[image: result]

Note how this code uses the `pygame.freetype` module instead of `pygame.font`, since it offers such nice functions as [`Font.render_to`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.render_to) and [`Font.get_rect`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/freetype.html#pygame.freetype.Font.get_rect).

Comment: Hmm, I am still have an error in font.origin, "AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'origin'. Note that: I am using python 3.6.3

Comment: Sorry to say, Can I ask one more question? I solved the above problem, but I am still one more error. It said,  AttributeError: "tuple" object has no attriubte "split" in    words = text.split(" ")

Comment: @sloth when I run the example, a `ValueError: text to long for the surface` gets raised. Does it work for you? I'll try to debug it later.

Comment: @RV3000Developer you have to pass a string as the `text` argument instead of a tuple.

Comment: @skrx The text is split into words, and that exception happens when the word is too large for the surface.

Comment: Yes, but why does it raise an exception for me with the same settings as in your example? Are our font sizes or the resolution different? `pygame.freetype.get_default_resolution()` returns 72.

Comment: @skrx returns `72` for me as well (using pygame 1.9.4, Python 2.7.11, 64-bit Windows).  I guess you could add something like `print word, bounds, height, y` after `bounds = font.get_rect(word)` to see where the problem is

Comment: For `'Hello'` it prints `Hello <rect(1, 15, 41, 15)> 200 25`. I'm using pygame 1.9.4, Python 3.7 (also checked out 3.5) and 64-bit Windows as well.